# Dump, compress, upload, import a mysql DB via SSH

Tags: mysql, ssh

How would I write a script that will run a mysqldump on a database zip it up then scp it and then import it into the database on the server via ssh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

works for me:

```
mysqldump --opt --single-transaction <DB_NAME> | pigz -2 | ssh -p <PORT> <HOST> 'cat - | gunzip -c | mysql <DB_NAME_DEST>'
```

Comment: How about `ssh -Cp` instead? Letting SSH take care of compression.